# How to disable todo warnings in sonarlint plugin for IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, suppress-warnings, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

The SonarLint plugin for Intellij gives warnings for TODOs as well.

By default Intellij highlights TODOs and displays them in a Commit Dialog as well. SonarLint highlighting it again is redundant.

Also, it suppresses one useful feature of Intellij - Intellij highlights TODOs with blue colour which is easier to recognize and scroll to.

Because of the SonarLint plugin, this feature is suppressed. So, I want to disable sonarlint warnings for to-do items only. How can I do that?

Comment: Please consider reviewing my answer and checking if it helped you out (I know it's been a while, perhaps this answer could help others as well).
Respectfully, Rann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, you can not ignore rules using the SL (SonarLint) plugin alone.

In order to do so, you must connect to a SQ (SonarQube) server.

The SQ server allows you not only to ignore all the instances of a single rule, but rather to ignore specific instances and allow other instances to appear.

In your case you would simply be disabling the [RSPEC-1135](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/type/Code%20Smell/RSPEC-1135) rule.

References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarlint/Hfen0FcDteg
- https://www.sonarlint.org/intellij/howto.html
- [Sonar category of TODO warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980607/sonar-category-of-todo-warnings)
- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube

Comment: Thanks! But I just use sonarlint plugin in my IDEA. It's not connected to server :(

Comment: @NagabhushanSN I highly recommend you try SonarQube. SonarLint just scratches the surface :)

Comment: @NagabhushanSN : HTH (Happy To Help). Take care buddy.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the highlighting issue: You need to go to Settings > Editor > SonarLint, then click on "Info issue", disable "Inherit values from" and set your preferred error stripe mark.

[image]